Running Selenium from the Command Line forcing use of specific profile
I am attempting to utilize Selenium to do some simple automated testing of some web applications my team supports and would prefer to do this testing without the implementation of a testing framework as these are very simple tests and most members of the team are not knowledgeable of the framework languages supported. I see that Selenium tests can be run through the command line (Side-Runner), the issue I am running into is due to the implementation of SSO, an authentication window is thrown during the running of test scripts via Side-Runner. I know that I can force the driver (at least the Chrome driver) to use a specific profile, but that leads me back to having to use a test framework to programmatically force the use of a profile. Is there any way to force Selenium/browser driver to use a specific profile via command line arguments or without having to code it at the browser driver creation level? In my exhaustive search of the internet, I have found that Selenium can be passed a "profileTemplate" for Firefox, but that appears to be only related to Selenium RC from what I can tell. Is this correct? Any ideas or even other tools that someone could suggest that could be used with Selenium that would not require coding knowledge that my other team members do not possess would be greatly appreciated.

it's just a launch flag, so should be possible...  chrome.exe  --user-data-dir="path_to_profile"
